# Profiling thread sync lock contention

Tags: .net, multithreading, profiling, performance, parallel-processing

In the past I've used performance profiling tools such as nprof, Equatec profiler and Yourkit profiler to identify and remove/reduce performance bottlenecks in code mostly running in one thread (serialized execution). Nowadays I write a lot of multi-threaded code which can be slowed down by lock contention; what tools and tricks can be used to identify where lock contention is occuring and by how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available soon, currently shipping in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2.  Here's a [video of the tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20170713074106/http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Visualizing-Concurrency-Inside-the-Concurrency-Visualizer-Profiling-Tool/).  The landing page that tells you how to download and install the concurrency visualizer is [currently here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/concurrency-visualizer?view=vs-2022).

Comment: Very interesting. This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. For those interested these tools are available in the freely available Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2; However, be sure to get the Premium or Ultimate editions. Also the thread visualizations shown in linked video are only available under some operating systems - they weren't available on my XP box but were enabled on my Vista box (both 64bit BTW).

Answer (score 1):

Try [ThreadChecker](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-thread-checker/) from Intel. It works on both Windows and Linux. If you're working on Windows, then try [Parallel Studio](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-parallel-studio-home/). It provides a easy-to-use locks-and-waits profiler. It shows overall concurrency during the runtime, which gives hints on lock contentions and poor concurrency. The tools are doing right now what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For developing on Windows, Software Verification have some [(http://www.softwareverify.com/thread.html)](http://www.softwareverify.com/thread.html).

For C, C++, Delphi try Thread Validator.

For Java, there is also Java Thread Validator.

There are also experimental versions for Python and Ruby.