# Does using a Castle singleton cause contention in ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, castle-windsor

I'm using a readonly dictionary object in a class instantiated with a Singleton lifestyle in an ASP.NET. There's no locking around access to the dictionary object.

Would you expect there to be any .NET contention around reading from this object, given that there may be many web requests accessing it at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is actually about dictionary thread-safety, Windsor is unrelated.

Assuming you're using the standard .NET collections,
the [MSDN docs for `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) say:

> A Dictionary(TKey, TValue) can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

But it's not thread-safe if you have concurrent writers, which means that it probably doesn't lock anything internally, so I wouldn't expect any contention.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. My app is being performance tested and high levels of .NET contention are being reported. However, given that there's no locking involved in this, then I can't see that this would have any bearing on it. What do you think?

Comment: "high levels of .NET contention are being reported" -> how do they test it? Why doesn't the test point to the source?

Comment: It's occuring during a stress test. They're measuring using .NET contention performance counter so it's difficult to know immediately where in app it could be occurring

Comment: @Mark909 : have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222826/profiling-net-thread-contention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169143/profiling-thread-sync-lock-contention

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll give that a try. Thanks for all your help with this question, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Castle Windsor do you use ?
Its a bug in 3.2 version - https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/34

Just upgrade version